# Is debt eventually negative for nonnegative $y_t\to 0,c_t\not\to 0$?

Tags: mathematical-economics, international-trade

Suppose $d_t=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k (y_{t+k}-c_{t+k})$ and $\rho\in (0,1),y_t\geq 0,c_t>0\quad \forall t\geq 0$. Does $y_t\to 0,c_t\not\to 0$ imply $d_t$ is eventually negative?

My initial hunch was affirmative, but I want to be sure.

I have already shown that for generic sequence $z_t$, we have $$z_t \to z\iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k z_{t+k}\to z/(1-\rho).$$

So $c_t\not\to 0$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k c_{t+k}\not\to 0.$ Hence $\exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k c_{t+k}>\epsilon$ for infinitely many $t$.

Meanwhile, $y_t\to 0$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k y_{t+k}\to 0$ so for some $T$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k y_{t+k}<\epsilon$ for $t\geq T$.

So $d_t$ should be negative infinitely often but can we say it is eventually always negative?

Answer (score 2):

No, though coming up with a concrete counterexample is a messy business.

Let $y_t=\rho^t$. Then $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k y_{t+k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^{2k+t}=\frac{\rho^t}{1-\rho^2}.$$
Let $c_t=1$ if $t=n^n$ for some $n$ and $c_t=0$ otherwise. Let $t=n^n+1$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k c_{t+k}\leq\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^{k+(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n-1}=\frac{\rho^{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n-1}}{1-\rho}<\frac{\rho^{n\cdot n^n}}{1-\rho}=\frac{\rho^{nt}}{1-\rho}.$$ So for large $n$, we have $d_t>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that $d_t$ is eventually negative because of the Theorem of Sign Permanence for sequences. I recall it below:

> ***Theorem.*** Let  ${a_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers. And suppose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n=l>0$,   $l\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Then exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>n_0$ $a_n>0$.

(The converse if $l<0$, of course).

A series of real number is a sequence, the sequence of partial sums, and the sum of a series is the limit of that sequence, so the theorem applies.

Your series converges to a negative number, $z/(1-\rho)$, where $z$ is the limit of $(y_{k+k} -c_{t+k})$, so the series is eventually negative.

Comment: Thanks for the post!  I thought about this further. In my setup, $c_t$ is not necessarily converging to a positive number; it may vacillate arbitrarily close to zero infinitely often (in a way that outpaces $y_t\to 0)$, in which case I think $d_t$ may be negative infinitely often.  But a counterexample would make this concrete.

Comment: I see, I agree with you. But, then, you don't know if $y_{t+k}-c_{t+k}$ converges, so you can't apply the formula   $$z_t \to z\iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k z_{t+k}\to z/(1-\rho).$$ . Moreover, does $d_t$ converge? How can you prove it?

Comment: Correct, from the assumptions, $d_t$ need not converge.

Comment: I think that if $d_t$ doesn't converge, you cant't say nothing about $d_t$ beeing eventually negative. For example, let $\rho=1/2$ and $z=y_{t+k}-c_{t+k}=-2^k$. The series becomes $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1/2)^k(-2)^k= 1-1+1-1+1....$ , which alternates negative and positive terms.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify. $d_t$ is well-defined so that the series that defines it is a convergent series. However, the sequence $(d_t)_{t\geq 0}$ need not converge.

Comment: Is see. You mean the sequence $(d_t)$, $t=0,....\infty$, not the series $d_t$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139188/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-bakerstreet).